# Update postmeta Parent when post_status child change

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, post-meta, post-status

I have custom status = completed.
I want to set automatically when child post update status 'completed'. their parent's postmeta also change.

here my code:

```
 add_action('save_post', 'update_status_parent_when_completed');
function update_status_parent_when_completed(){

        /** Ensure this is the correct Post Type*/
        if($post_type !== 'screening')
        return;

        if ($post->post_status == 'completed'){

            $parent_id = get_the_ID($post->post_parent);
            update_post_meta($parent_id, 'screening_status', 'screen');

        }
    }
```

but nothing happen with parent_post. Please teach me the correct way.

Comment: `$post->post_parent` _is_ the ID, you don't need `get_the_ID()`, which doesn't even accept arguments. You're also not defining the `$post` or `$post_type` variables anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WP 3.7 you have the option to hook to the `save_post` hook directly for you post_type.

For example:

```
function update_post_parent_status_on_complete( $post_id ) {
    if(!isset($post))
      $post = get_post($post_id);

    // checking the status you want and also that has a parent
    if ($post->post_status == 'completed' && $post->post_parent !=0 ){
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
        update_post_meta($parent_id, 'screening_status', 'screen');
    }
}

add_action('save_post_screening', 'update_post_parent_status_on_complete');
```